# how can I auto fit FullCalendar into a specified div space

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to fit fullCalendar into a specified div space giving it a fluid effect but find it hard to do.  I even tried using the aspect ratio but not getting any luck.... below is what I did so far

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
    var ratio = $(window).width()/$(window).height();
    $('.resize').html('<div>ratio:'+ratio+'</div>');
    calendar.fullCalendar('option', 'aspectRatio', ratio);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Adjusting dynamically the **height** instead of the **aspect ratio** worked for me:

Asigning the calendar to a variable when initiating:

```
calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: $(window).height()*0.83,
    ...
});
```

And then adjusting height dynamically (after checking that calendar exists already in order to avoid initial error messages):

```
if(calendar) {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var calHeight = $(window).height()*0.83;
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', calHeight);
  });
};
```

The factor `*0.83` depends on your page-design.

Hope this helps.
[image: English, weekview]
[image: Spanish, dayview]

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to set the `height` property dynamically:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/height/

Comment: Hey its not working, rendered height exceeding container. and I have a problem i.e; When initially full calendar not displaying the view after click on next or prev only displaying the view. missing anything? Thanks in advance.